# Need to convert to byte object. I have failed

Tags: python

I am using a gps and raspberry pi for a dash cam. I get an error saying it should be a bytes-like object not a str for "if gps_str.find('GGA') > 0:

```
while(time.time() < timeout):
        gps_str = serialPort.readline()
        if gps_str.find('GGA') > 0:
            msg = pynmea2.parse(gps_str)
```

Comment: `gps_str.find(b'GGA')`?

Comment: soooo thank you...... I guess I was way over thinking this haha

Comment: I'm glad you got a solution. But please keep your question title to just the facts.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `gps_str.find(b'GGA')`, instead of `gps_str.find('GGA')` Try that and it should work fine!